# CSS: wrap text around boxes independent of element order

Tags: html, css

I am generating headings, text and boxes and want to wrap the text around boxes. Is there an easy way to let the text wrap, even if the `<p>` element is in front of the `<div>`?

For example, I want the behavior of `box 1`, even if the elements are placed like `box 2`. https://jsfiddle.net/7wnat86b/

```css
h3 {
  clear: left;
}

.box {
  float: left;
  clear: left;
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h3>
    This is a heading.
  </h3>
  <div class="box">
    box 1
  </div>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quas culpa voluptas quod eveniet voluptatem rerum quasi voluptates, assumenda itaque inventore maiores. Exercitationem nam quia id voluptatum, itaque quisquam eligendi ullam.
  </p>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quas culpa voluptas quod eveniet voluptatem rerum quasi voluptates, assumenda itaque inventore maiores. Exercitationem nam quia id voluptatum, itaque quisquam eligendi ullam.
  </p>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quas culpa voluptas quod eveniet voluptatem rerum quasi voluptates, assumenda itaque inventore maiores. Exercitationem nam quia id voluptatum, itaque quisquam eligendi ullam.
  </p>
  <h3>
    Another heading.
  </h3>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quas culpa voluptas quod eveniet voluptatem rerum quasi voluptates, assumenda itaque inventore maiores. Exercitationem nam quia id voluptatum, itaque quisquam eligendi ullam.
  </p>
  <div class="box">
    box 2
  </div>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quas culpa voluptas quod eveniet voluptatem rerum quasi voluptates, assumenda itaque inventore maiores. Exercitationem nam quia id voluptatum, itaque quisquam eligendi ullam.
  </p>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quas culpa voluptas quod eveniet voluptatem rerum quasi voluptates, assumenda itaque inventore maiores. Exercitationem nam quia id voluptatum, itaque quisquam eligendi ullam.
  </p>
</div>
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What do you mean by _`p` in front of `div`_?

Comment: so you want to make box2 upper?

Comment: I want to make box 2 render like box 1, by adding to the `box` class. With `p` in front of `div` I mean that, in the html, the order of elements is `<p>..</p><div class="box"></div>` instead of `<div class="box"></div><p>..</p>`.

Comment: Flexbox offers a property called "order". If your wrapper is set to display: flex; and flex-direction:column; you could target your .box class and set it upper by doing: p + .box { order: -1}. But it involve wrapping your h3 / p / .box in a div set to display flex.. But my solution is just OK if your .box div is at position 0 or 1... You should definitly have the right html structure to get the result you want. Or another solution would be to set your .box class to position: absolute, top: 0; And its parent to position: relative; padding-top: XXpx; But it is not a good solution either ! ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***NOTE: This solution uses Javascipt to achieve the results***

I am pretty sure you want to place the second paragraph proceeding the second H3 tag so it lays out just like the first box/h3/p tags in terms of layout... yes?

**This can be achieved using vanilla javascript** by creating a nodelist and checking the nodelists sibling elements tag to see if they match the H3 tag. If they do not, then you know the previous sibling element to the target element, *the box element*, is a paragraph. You can then create a new element, assign its textContent to that of the previousElementsSiblings textContent. Then use `insertAdjacentHTML()` after the end of the value.

This is achieved in the snippit below using a forEach loop that loops through the box elements to check their previous siblings, if the previous siblings tag is not a `H3` tag, we run code to create a new `p` tag, then assign the value of the `textContent` of the `previousElementSibling` to the newly created `p` element. Then we use the `insertAdjacentHTML` function to insert the newly created element into the document using the key `afterend` ***`position`*** directly after the box element in question. Lastly we remove the old element, essentially repositioning the elements so that they reflect the desired styling you want with regard to layout.

```js
let boxes = document.querySelectorAll('.box');
let mainDiv = document.querySelector("#main")
boxes.forEach(function(v,i){
    if(v.previousElementSibling.tagName !== 'H3'){
      let p = document.createElement('P')
      p.textContent = v.previousElementSibling.textContent;
      v.insertAdjacentHTML("afterend", p.textContent = v.previousElementSibling.textContent);
      v.previousElementSibling.remove();
    }
})
```

```css
h3 {
  clear: left;
}

.box {
  float: left;
  clear: left;
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <h3>
    This is a heading.
  </h3>
  <div class="box">
    box 1
  </div>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quas culpa voluptas quod eveniet voluptatem rerum quasi voluptates, assumenda itaque inventore maiores. Exercitationem nam quia id voluptatum, itaque quisquam eligendi ullam.
  </p>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quas culpa voluptas quod eveniet voluptatem rerum quasi voluptates, assumenda itaque inventore maiores. Exercitationem nam quia id voluptatum, itaque quisquam eligendi ullam.
  </p>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quas culpa voluptas quod eveniet voluptatem rerum quasi voluptates, assumenda itaque inventore maiores. Exercitationem nam quia id voluptatum, itaque quisquam eligendi ullam.
  </p>
  <h3>
    Another heading.
  </h3>
  <p>
    This is the text I want to move and be just like the text next to box 1. This is the text I want to move and be just like the text next to box 1. This is the text I want to move and be just like the text next to box 1. This is the text I want to move and be just like the text next to box 1. 
  </p>
  <div class="box">
    box 2
  </div>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quas culpa voluptas quod eveniet voluptatem rerum quasi voluptates, assumenda itaque inventore maiores. Exercitationem nam quia id voluptatum, itaque quisquam eligendi ullam.
  </p>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quas culpa voluptas quod eveniet voluptatem rerum quasi voluptates, assumenda itaque inventore maiores. Exercitationem nam quia id voluptatum, itaque quisquam eligendi ullam.
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Just in case here is a CSS Flex-box solution that works... Even if I don't recommend.

```css
.sub-wrapper {
display: flex;
flex-wrap: wrap;
align-items: center;
}

h3 {
flex: 0 100%;
order: -1000;
}

.box {
order: -100;
height: 100px;
background: green;
flex: 0 30%;
}

h3 + p, .box + p {
flex: 0 70%;
}

p, p + .box + p{
width: 100%;
flex: 0 100%;
}
```

```html
<div>
<div class="sub-wrapper">
  <h3>
    This is a heading.
  </h3>
  <div class="box">
    box 1
  </div>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quas culpa voluptas quod eveniet voluptatem rerum quasi voluptates, assumenda itaque inventore maiores. Exercitationem nam quia id voluptatum, itaque quisquam eligendi ullam.
  </p>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quas culpa voluptas quod eveniet voluptatem rerum quasi voluptates, assumenda itaque inventore maiores. Exercitationem nam quia id voluptatum, itaque quisquam eligendi ullam.
  </p>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quas culpa voluptas quod eveniet voluptatem rerum quasi voluptates, assumenda itaque inventore maiores. Exercitationem nam quia id voluptatum, itaque quisquam eligendi ullam.
  </p>
  </div>
  <div class="sub-wrapper">
  <h3>
    Another heading.
  </h3>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quas culpa voluptas quod eveniet voluptatem rerum quasi voluptates, assumenda itaque inventore maiores. Exercitationem nam quia id voluptatum, itaque quisquam eligendi ullam.
  </p>
  <div class="box">
    box 2
  </div>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quas culpa voluptas quod eveniet voluptatem rerum quasi voluptates, assumenda itaque inventore maiores. Exercitationem nam quia id voluptatum, itaque quisquam eligendi ullam.
  </p>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quas culpa voluptas quod eveniet voluptatem rerum quasi voluptates, assumenda itaque inventore maiores. Exercitationem nam quia id voluptatum, itaque quisquam eligendi ullam.
  </p>
  </div>
</div>
```